# mock instance is null after @Mock annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I try to run this test:

```
    @Mock IRoutingObjHttpClient routingClientMock;
    @Mock IRoutingResponseRepository routingResponseRepositoryMock;


    @Test
    public void testSendRoutingRequest() throws Exception {
        CompleteRoutingResponse completeRoutingResponse = new CompleteRoutingResponse();
        completeRoutingResponse.regression_latencyMillis = 500L;

        Mockito.when(routingClientMock.sendRoutingRequest(any(RoutingRequest.class))).thenReturn(completeRoutingResponse);

        RoutingObjHttpClientWithReRun routingObjHttpClientWithReRun = new RoutingObjHttpClientWithReRun
                (routingClientMock, routingResponseRepositoryMock);

...
    }
```

but I get NullPointerException for:

`Mockito.when(routingClientMock.`

what am i missing?

Comment: Do you call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`? (Should probably be in @Before method) Or, do you have any other @Rule which you expect to initialize your mocks? (It isn't automagic)

Comment: You need to instantiate the `routingClientMock` e.g. `routingClientMock = Mockito.mock(RoutingObjHtttpClient.class);`

Comment: You could also use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` at your class

Comment: please write as an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: In my case (not the case for this question), I was trying to mock a dependency for another Mock for the UUT (i.e. two layers of mocks). This does not work trivially, and so the second layer mock was null.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

When you want to use the `@Mock` annotation you should use the `MockitoJUnitRunner`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {

    @Mock
    private IRoutingObjHttpClient routingClientMock;

    @Test
    public void testSendRoutingRequest() throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

}
```

See also [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mockito_usage).

Comment: It doesnt work for me always gives this error "dexcache == null (and no default could be found; consider setting the 'dexmaker.dexcache' system property)"

Comment: @pyus13 This should be a new question with more code.

Comment: Appreciate the response, I think the problem was I was using it in JUnit Test and while some code merges someone from team mistakenly added dex maker testImplementation dependencies. After removing that line from build.gradle things were started working. Thanks hope this will save someone's time.

Comment: By using @Mock annotation  this giving a build failed.

Comment: @David I think your problem should be a new question with a complete example.

Comment: @RolandWeisleder sure. Let me post a question.

Comment: that tutorial is trash

Answer (score 86):

Same problem can occur if you are using Junit5 since there is no more '@RunWith' annotation.

In this case you should annotate your class with:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTestClass {
...
```

You should also import into your dependency (Maven - pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 73):

You have three options for activating the `@Mock` annotation: MockitoRule, MockitoJUnitRunner, MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this). IMHO using the `MockitoRule` is the best one, because it lets you still choose another runner like e.g. `Parameterized`.

### Use the [MockitoRule](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html)

```
public class MockitoTest {

  @Mock
  private IRoutingObjHttpClient routingClientMock;

  @Rule
  public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Test
  public void testSendRoutingRequest() throws Exception {
    // ...
  }
}
```

### Use the [MockitoJUnitRunner](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {

  @Mock
  private IRoutingObjHttpClient routingClientMock;

  @Test
  public void testSendRoutingRequest() throws Exception {
    // ...
  }
}
```

### Call [MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) explicitly.

This can be done in qn `@Before` method, in your own runner or in an own rule.

```
public class MockitoTest {

  @Mock
  private IRoutingObjHttpClient routingClientMock;

  @Before
  public void createMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSendRoutingRequest() throws Exception {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: In most of the test classes @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) works fine in injecting mocks. But in few test classes both @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) and MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) worked together only. Is there any explaination for this issue ?

Comment: Can you please create another question on StackOverflow with a complete example.

Answer (score 39):

If you use `junit.jupiter` with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` for test class but **mocks are null**, ensure that `@Test` annotation is imported from

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

instead of `org.junit.Test;`

Comment: after all the above failed this import was the one which worked. Thankyou Rammgarot

Comment: Thanks! This was it, I was upgrading some old tests from JUnit 4 to 5 and forgot that one

Answer (score 11):

What solved this issue for me (combination of answers above and my own additions):

- `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in the `@Before` method
- Test class must be public
- Test methods must be public
- `import org.junit.Test;` instead of `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

When doing command + N --> `Test...` in Intellij it generates (as a default at least) some boilerplate that did not work in my case.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me. My issue was the last one you commented on. Much love!

Comment: My scenario includes `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Parameterized.class)`. For each param declared under `@Parameterized.Parameters` the `@Before` annotations invokes some mocked objects `null`. Without parameters, tests run fine, no NPE. With parameteres, needed `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, my IDE was importing org.testng.annotations.Test by default. I had to change it to org.junit.Test and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

For me, even after adding `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` it was not working.
Turned out, I had made the silly mistake of importing `@Test` from

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

instead of

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

After correcting it, it worked!

Answer (score 6):

Add **@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)** annotation  to the test class and it should work given You are using Junit 5+ version.
If you are using older version of Junit use **@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)** annotation.

Answer (score 4):

1. You should use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` at your class
2. You have to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in @Before method

Comment: why `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and not `MockitoJUnitRunner.class` ?

Comment: You don't need SpringJUnit4ClassRunner unless you want to wire in some Spring context into your test - which is a very twisty passage of its own.

Answer (score 4):

It can also be an import problem, so make sure you have the appropriate imported package.

For example, the "org.easymock" package also does have an annotation called @Mock, which of course, won't work with Mockito specific setup.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem that I declared @Mock MyClass myClass and then tried to mock a behaviour inside my @BeforeAll annotated method:

```
@Mock
private MyClass myClass;

...

@BeforeAll
public void init()
{
    ...
    Mockito.when(myClass.something()).thenReturn("Not found")
    ...
}
```

Apparently init() was executed before the mock initialization of myClass, so myClass == null inside init().

The solution was to change the annotation from @BeforeAll to @BeforeEach.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but it says that `init()` must be static

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina this is expected, because the method will be class-scope, you either have to make it static or apply `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` on your test class. Or, as stated in the answer, you can change to `@BeforeEach` which will make it method-scope (will be called before calling each method annotated with `@Test`).

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked when I added :

1. At class level:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class).
```

2. Inside class:

```
@Before
      public void createMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      }
```

Comment: One of them is enough for use @mock annotation

Answer (score 1):

Try to to check if the method that you are calling is a **final** method or not.

Mockito cannot mock the final method. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Junit 5 with InjectMocks. Based on above suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/55616702/2643815

```
 @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClientTest {
@Mock
    Environment environment;
    @Mock
    ClassCreator classCreator;

    @InjectMocks
    MyClient myClient;


    @Test
    public void mytest() {
            myClient = new MyClient(environment, classCreator);
            
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the annotation to the class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

and modifying the version of Mockito solved this issue.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I found updating my tests (which were originally written for JUnit 3 and used the legacy `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods) to JUnit 4 and modern annotated fixture methods worked.

Additionally, if you're using the Rule:

```
@Rule public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
```

Make sure the rule is also on a public class or you will receive the message:

```
How did getFields return a field we couldn't access?
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution in comments that worked for me. Do this for all the mocks you are creating.

*You need to instantiate the routingClientMock e.g.*

```java
routingClientMock = Mockito.mock(RoutingObjHtttpClient.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was trying to mock an object which was final in my service. Just needed to remove final and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for answering! However, questions do not belong in answers, which is why I've removed it. You can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), leaving a link to this post, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

our application uses `JUNIT5` , same issue occured.
I replaced `@Mock` with `@InjectMocks` - then issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

**My Code**

1. It had JUnit version ->

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Was running on java 8

**Solution**

Change `@Test` to import from -

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

instead of -

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are also using PowerMock then

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

can be replaced with

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

This will activate your `@Mocks` and enable the PowerMock functionality.