# @Mock object instance is null

Tags: java, junit, mockito

@Mock object instance is null .

I am doing this is my test class

```
@Mock
private SchoolRequest schoolRequest;

@InjectMock
private FormRequest formRequest;

@Before
public void init(){
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

Class FormRequest {

@Autowired 
private SchoolRequest schoolRequest;


}
```

This application is running properly, but in test cases `schoolRequest` is coming as null.  Any pointer on why it might happen ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample code which reproduces your problem?

Comment: it's very big code base. can't put whole code .

Comment: is SchoolRequest final?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski , No it's not,

Comment: Where are your test methods located? Are they in the same class as init()?  Perhaps put a breakpoint on the initMocks() call and run one of your tests in debug to see if it's called.

Comment: Yes, They are in same class. I did put the breakpoint. this is called.

Comment: @davida. I have a solution which is working. I have listed it in answers. But i don't know why this is working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the reason but this worked.

```
private SchoolRequest schoolRequest = Mockito.mock(SchoolRequest.class);
```

May be someone can comment why this worked. What is difference between `@Mock` and `Mockito.mock` . I thought they are same.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are missing @RunWith annotation on class level. Whenever you want to use the @Mock annotation you should use the MockitoJUnitRunner.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {
@Mock
private SchoolRequest schoolRequest;

@InjectMock
private FormRequest formRequest;

@Before
public void init(){
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
}
```

I hope this should work for you..

Comment: It's one of the option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590621/mock-instance-is-null-after-mock-annotation