# Mock and InjectMocks return NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

So I have a simple class Movie with String name, String title and 2 other double fields.

Everytime I run, it gives me NullPointerException on repository saying that it is null.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MovieServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private MovieService movieService;
    
    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void findByTitleSucces(){
        Movie requestMovie=new Movie("Test","genreTest",2,2);
        Movie saved=new Movie(1,"Test","genreTest",2,2);
        

Mockito.when(movieRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(saved);

        Movie created = movieService.add(requestMovie).getBody();
        Movie responseMovie = movieService.findByTitle("Test").getBody();

        assertNotNull(created);
    }
```

Comment: I think this link might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590621/mock-instance-is-null-after-mock-annotation/29599822

Comment: Looks like you are trying to mix JUnit4 and JUnit5 annotations and ways to launch a test, that will obviously not work.

Comment: Check your import statements for Test annotation, the right package would be  org.junit.Test.

Comment: Is the class and method public ?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I was using default junit5, and trying to solve it with junit4, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In **JUnit5** the `@RunWith` annotation is deprecated, instead, you can use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` for JUnit5.

The following example shows how to mock a class's dependencies with JUnit5, in addition to using the `@Mock` and `@InjectMock` annotations. This fixes the null instances issue (NullPointerException)

Comment: thks, it works for me!