# Mockito @Mock and @InjectMocks are null

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, mockito

I am trying to test this (anonymized) code:

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import com.dummy.domain.dummy.dao.MatchDAO;

@Service
public class TeamService {

    private MatchDAO matchDAO;

    public TeamService(MatchDAO matchDAO) {
        this.matchDAO = matchDAO;
    }

    public Team get(int teamId) {
        return get(teamId, LocalDate.now());
    }

    public Team get(int teamId, LocalDate date) {
        matchDAO.findMatchIdsForTeam(teamId, date);
        ...
    }
}
```

Using the following test code:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TeamServiceTest {
    @Mock
    MatchDAO matchDAO;

    @InjectMocks
    TeamService teamService;

//    @BeforeAll
//    public void createMocks() {
//        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
//    }

    @Test
    public void testGetTeam() {
        when(matchDAO.findMatchIdsForTeam(anyInt(), any(LocalDate.class))).thenReturn(new int[]{1234, 5678});

        Team team = teamService.get(1);
        ... assertions
    }
}
```

But I keep getting either this error:

```
[ERROR] com.dummy.domain.dummy.TeamServiceTest.testGetTeam()  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.dummy.domain.dummy.TeamService.get(int, java.time.LocalDate)" because "this.TeamService" is null
```

Or this error:

```
[ERROR] com.dummy.domain.dummy.TeamServiceTest.testGetTeam()  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.dummy.domain.dummy.dao.MatchDAO.findMatchIdsForTeam(int, java.time.LocalDate)" because "this.TeamService" is null
```

Some tests give the error that @InjectMocks object is null and some tests give the error that the @Mock is null.

I tried it with the @BeforeAll enabled and disabled (and also as @BeforeEach). I also tried with SpringExtension instead of MockitoExtension. I have also tried many suggestions including all stated in this post: [mock instance is null after mock annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590621/mock-instance-is-null-after-mock-annotation)

Interestingly when running this test in maven it fails but when I try to run it in my IDE (Intellij) it is succesful. I checked and both are using the same JDK and maven version. Running it in our build pipeline is also giving the same error as local maven build.

Can anyone help with this problem?

For reference this is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dummy.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Update:
The xml has a parent pom with the following content:
(Updated based on @khmarbaise comment)

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M8</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit-jupiter.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Your `TeamService` class has an explicit constructor. That may be interfering with Mockito. Why not explicitly create instances in a `@BeforeEach` method? The mock should already be set at that time.

Comment: @RobSpoor I tried it and that doesn't change anything

Comment: Is this the whole pom file..because spring-boot-test is given? Which version of spring boot...also which version of Mockito is used? Also which version of junit-jupiter is used?

Comment: @khmarbaise I updated the post, it has a parent pom which I added now.

Comment: First remove the junit-jupiter-engine and asm at surefire-plugin ... better is to define the most recent version of surefireplugin instead... also remove `junit-platform-surefire-provider.` does not make sense... and retest... (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) and add the junit-jupiter-engine as dependency instead of the junit-jupiter-api...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I did what you mentioned and still got the same error

Comment: Please make an example on github or alike...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I fixed the issue myself. I replaced the dependencies on
`junit-jupiter-api`, `spring-boot-test`, `spring-test`, and `mockito-junit-jupiter` with a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-test`. Even though the starter is using the same dependencies with the same versions I explicitly used, it did fix it.